# Use button with *ngIf Directive within matDatepicker in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I'm trying to show the remove button within a matDatepicker on a specific condition in that way every time  Datepicker has valued the remove button show in order to clear the value of matDatepicker and it works until use *ngIf Directive, When I use *ngIf I can't see any button element within datePicker.
please anyone knows help me.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
           <mat-form-field class="matfield full-width">
                <input matInput formControlName="dateTo" [matDatepicker]="pickerTo" placeholder="To Date"
                                (dateChange)="setDate('dateTo', $event)"/>
                       <button *ngIf="formGroup.value.dateTo" mat-button mat-icon-button matSuffix 
                                (click)="resetDateTo()">
                                <mat-icon [inline]="true">close</mat-icon>
                       </button>

                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerTo"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #pickerTo disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**TS**

```js
    // TicketFilterFormValues interface
    formGroup = new FormGroup({
        ticketNo: new FormControl(),
        serialNo: new FormControl(),
        branchCode: new FormControl(),
        ticketStatus: new FormControl(),
        dateFrom: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
        dateTo: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
        state: new FormControl(),
        city: new FormControl(),
        description: new FormControl(),
    });

resetDateFrom() {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
            dateFrom: '',
        });
    }

    resetDateTo() {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
            dateTo: ''
        });
    }
```

[image: datepicker]

Comment: when you has a formControl disabled, this is not in form.value, you need use getRawValue() https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue: `<button *ngIf="formGroup.getRawValue().dateTo"...>`: NOTE: if it's disabled be sure that the mat-datepicker is disabled: `[disabled]="formGroup.get('DateTo').disabled"`

Comment: My problem solved and thanks for your description and your advice.

Comment: @Eliseo add your answer since this helped resolving the problem to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Eliseo answer, it worked now by this approach.

```html
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                    <mat-form-field class="matfield full-width">
                        <input matInput formControlName="dateFrom" [matDatepicker]="pickerFrom"
                            placeholder="fromDate" (dateChange)="setDate('dateFrom', $event)" />
                        <button *ngIf="formGroup.getRawValue().dateFrom" mat-button mat-icon-button matSuffix
                            (click)="resetDateFrom()">
                            <mat-icon [inline]="true">close</mat-icon>
                        </button>

                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                      <mat-datepicker #pickerFrom disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
                  </mat-form-field>
             </div>
```